# Webpage design with embedded flash flv videos

Tags: html, flv

I need to create a webpage for a family website that has a video section in it. There are about 50 videos that the server will be hosting.  I'm looking for an photo album like list where people can scroll through and click on a video and start watching it. Are there any good webpage templates that someone can point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [zenphoto](http://www.zenphoto.org/)?   http://www.zenphoto.org/support/topic.php?id=1126